# Android Firebase Authentication client purpose of API key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have built an app which uses Firebase database and Firebase storage. Currently, the security rules are set to 'public' access which I do believe is not secure.

I read somewhere in the documentation that anybody with the Firebase URL link for my app database can access the DB (since it is set to 'public' access). Is it entirely correct? What about the API key? Isn't the API key generated and stored in my config file to available only to my app? Can any other client connect to the database without the API key?